# Using Stripe Customer metadata to store password

Tags: stripe-payments

I’m looking at building a solution that allows for users to have an account with my website that is linked somehow to their corresponding stripe customer account. The way I am currently doing this is by using an external database server which holds customer account info such as email, password and stripe customer id. The stripe customer id is used to look up stored credit cards and billing info for the user. The problem I have with this current implementation is that the only reason why I am using an external database for this is to store a password securely (hashed of course) and this seems a little unnecessary.

Another thought I did have was to take advantage of the metadata property of the stripe customer object to store the hashed password. This way all customers live in stripe and that’s it. Is there any issues with doing it this way?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against storing authentication credentials in metadata on a Stripe customer object. One of the problems you'll run into is that you can have multiple Stripe Customer objects with the same email address. Generally, hitting the Stripe API to list customers, then find the one with the matching metadata / password hashed combo is not ideal. I'd suggest considering a third party auth provider like auth0 if you don't want to store.

Comment: Thanks @w1zeman1p, ill check that out!

Answer (score -1):

Sounds plausible. Did you try it out?